# Using org.xmlunit.diff.NodeFilters in XMLUnit DiffBuilder

Tags: xmlunit

I am using the XMLUnit in JUnit to compare the results of tests. I have a problem wherein there is an Element in my XML which gets the CURRENT TIMESTAMP as the tests run and when compared with the expected output, the results will never match.

To overcome this, I read about using `org.xmlunit.diff.NodeFilters`, but do not have any examples on how to implement this. The code snippet I have is as below,

```java
final org.xmlunit.diff.Diff documentDiff = DiffBuilder
        .compare(sourcExp)                  
        .withTest(sourceActual)
        .ignoreComments()
        .ignoreWhitespace()                 
        //.withNodeFilter(Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
        .build();
    
return documentDiff.hasDifferences();
```

My problem is, how do I implement the `NodeFilter`? What parameter should be passed and should that be passed? There are no samples on this. The `NodeFilter` method gets `Predicate<Node>` as the IN parameter. What does `Predicate<Node>` mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code worked for me,

```
public final class IgnoreNamedElementsDifferenceListener implements
    DifferenceListener {

private Set<String> blackList = new HashSet<String>();

public IgnoreNamedElementsDifferenceListener(String... elementNames) {
    for (String name : elementNames) {
        blackList.add(name);
    }
}

public int differenceFound(Difference difference) {
    if (difference.getId() == DifferenceConstants.TEXT_VALUE_ID) {
        if (blackList.contains(difference.getControlNodeDetail().getNode()
                .getParentNode().getNodeName())) {
            return DifferenceListener.RETURN_IGNORE_DIFFERENCE_NODES_IDENTICAL;
        }
    }

    return DifferenceListener.RETURN_ACCEPT_DIFFERENCE;
}

public void skippedComparison(Node node, Node node1) {

}
```

Answer (score 3):

`Predicate` is a functional interface with a single `test` method that - in the case of `NodeFilter` receives a DOM `Node` as argument and returns a boolean. [javadoc of Predicate](http://www.xmlunit.org/api/java/2.2.1/org/xmlunit/util/Predicate.html)

An implementation of `Predicate<Node>` can be used to filter nodes for the difference engine and only those `Node`s for which the `Predicate` returns `true` will be compared. [javadoc of setNodeFilter](http://www.xmlunit.org/api/java/2.2.1/org/xmlunit/diff/DifferenceEngine.html#setNodeFilter(org.xmlunit.util.Predicate)), [User-Guide](https://github.com/xmlunit/user-guide/wiki/SelectingNodes#nodefilter-and-attributefilter)

Assuming your element containing the timestamp was called timestamp you'd use something like

```java
.withNodeFilter(new Predicate<Node>() {
    @Override
    public boolean test(Node n) {
        return !(n instanceof Element &&
            "timestamp".equals(Nodes.getQName(n).getLocalPart()));
    }
})
```

or using lambdas

```java
.withNodeFilter(n -> !(n instanceof Element &&
    "timestamp".equals(Nodes.getQName(n).getLocalPart())))
```

This uses XMLUnit's `org.xmlunit.util.Nodes` to get the element name more easily.

Comment: Tried the above method (first one), but it always takes only the Root element and does not work as expected. Even though I give the element name in "", it always takes only the Root element. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, got the logic backwards. You want to return `false` for the `timestamp` nodes as you want to ignore it. I'll edit the answer.